# SqlCommand CommandText with Value to String

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Currently my code is susceptible to SQL Injection as I just test it.

The way I used to retrieve a record from dbo.Account

```
var condition = String.Format("[Username] = '{0}' AND [Password] = '{1}' AND Active = 1", username, password);

var account = new Data.Account().Select(condition, string.Empty, 0, 0);

public List<Model.Account> Select(string condition, string orderBy, int limit = 0, int offset = 0)
{
    var list = new List<Model.Account>();
    var query = "SELECT " + TABLE_COLUMN + " FROM [DBO].[ACCOUNT]";

    if (condition != string.Empty) 
        query += " WHERE " + condition;

    if (orderBy != string.Empty || limit > 0) 
        query += " ORDER BY " (orderBy == string.Empty ? "ID DESC" : orderBy);

    if (limit > 0) 
        query += " OFFSET " + offset + " ROWS FETCH NEXT " + limit + " ROWS ONLY";

    using (var db = new SqlManager())
    {
        using (var reader = db.ExecuteReader(query))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var item = BindData(reader);
                list.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And right now I am trying to create a string using `SqlParameter` like this:

```
SqlCommand condition = new SqlCommand("[Username] = @Username AND [Password] = @Password");
condition.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
condition.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);

var account = GetAccountByCondition(condition.CommandText);
```

How can I achieve to get the `SqlCommand` string along with the username and password value included?

I am doing this way because my data access layer is generated via program. And the String.Format for condition is really wrong.

The `SqlManager` class I am using, for your reference:

```
public class SqlManager : IDisposable
{
    private SqlConnection _connection;

    public SqlConnection Connection
    {
        get { return _connection; }
    }

    private SqlCommand _command;

    public SqlCommand Command
    {
        get { return _command; }
    }

    private SqlTransaction _transaction;

    public SqlTransaction Transaction
    {
        get { return _transaction; }
    }

    private List<SqlParameter> _parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

    public List<SqlParameter> Parameters
    {
        get { return _parameters; }
        set { _parameters = value; }
    }

    public SqlManager()
    {
        var constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        _connection = new SqlConnection(constr);
        _command = new SqlCommand();
        _connection.Open();
    }

    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string commandText)
    {
        return ExecuteNonQuery(commandText, CommandType.Text);
    }

    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string commandText, CommandType commandType)
    {
        _command.Connection = _connection;
        _command.Transaction = _transaction;
        _command.CommandType = commandType;
        _command.CommandText = commandText;
        _command.Parameters.Clear();
        _command.Parameters.AddRange(_parameters.ToArray());

        return _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public object ExecuteScalar(string commandText)
    {
        return ExecuteScalar(commandText, CommandType.Text);
    }

    public object ExecuteScalar(string commandText, CommandType commandType)
    {
        _command.Connection = _connection;
        _command.Transaction = _transaction;
        _command.CommandType = commandType;
        _command.CommandText = commandText;
        _command.Parameters.Clear();
        _command.Parameters.AddRange(_parameters.ToArray());

        return _command.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    public IDataReader ExecuteReader(string commandText)
    {
        return ExecuteReader(commandText, CommandType.Text);
    }

    public IDataReader ExecuteReader(string commandText, CommandType commandType)
    {
        _command.Connection = _connection;
        _command.CommandType = commandType;
        _command.CommandText = commandText;
        _command.Parameters.Clear();
        _command.Parameters.AddRange(_parameters.ToArray());

        return _command.ExecuteReader();
    }

    public XmlReader ExecuteXml(string commandText)
    {
        return ExecuteXml(commandText, CommandType.Text);
    }

    public XmlReader ExecuteXml(string commandText, CommandType commandType)
    {
        _command.Connection = _connection;
        _command.CommandType = commandType;
        _command.CommandText = commandText;
        _command.Parameters.Clear();
        _command.Parameters.AddRange(_parameters.ToArray());

        return _command.ExecuteXmlReader();
    }

    public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string commandText)
    {
        return ExecuteDataTable(commandText, CommandType.Text);
    }

    public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string commandText, CommandType commandType)
    {
        _command.Connection = _connection;
        _command.CommandType = commandType;
        _command.CommandText = commandText;
        _command.Parameters.Clear();
        _command.Parameters.AddRange(_parameters.ToArray());

        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(_command.ExecuteReader());

        return dt;
    }

    public void AddParameter(string paraName, object objectValue)
    {
        AddParameter(paraName, objectValue, ParameterDirection.Input);
    }

    public void AddParameter(string paraName, object objectValue, ParameterDirection direction)
    {
        var para = new SqlParameter();
        para.ParameterName = paraName;
        para.Direction = direction;
        para.Value = objectValue;
        _parameters.Add(para);
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        _transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        if (_transaction != null)
        {
            _transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        if (_transaction != null)
        {
            _transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

        if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }

        _connection = null;
        _command = null;
        _transaction = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to get the full query as text, that defeats the purpose of using parameters; you'll have to do all injection prevention manually. Doesn't the `SqlManager` class you use have some inbuilt system that allows executing queries with parameters?

Comment: @Nyerguds hi, I have been referring to my senior's code. He left the company. I just edited the content and included the SqlManager class. I am not really sure how to use it. Sorry for all the troubles.

Comment: There's a `Parameters` property on your `SqlManager` class that sets the internal _parameters used in `ExecuteReader`. Use that.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There's a manager class involved though. I just wasn't aware OP had full access to its internals. OP should just have read the code behind `ExecuteReader` to see where the parameters were taken from.

Comment: @Nyerguds I removed my comment because the actual issue is that a former employee is involved. The base class shows a re-invention of ADO.NET with extra deadlocking *and* thread-safety issues - a *single* open connection for the the entire class's lifetime? A *single* command object?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I just noticed that too, ouch. Doesn't even clear its parameters after executing...

Comment: @Nyerguds the Add.Parameters are used in Data Access layer for Insert, Update, and Delete method. For select method, I have to build a string condition in advance to filter the data. I need to add parameter with value to my [condition] and convert to string.

Comment: Um. No, you don't. The database system _itself_ (`SqlConnection`) takes care of the parameters inside the query.

Comment: @Maki92 are you sure you want to use that code? It's fundamentally wrong and will lead to deadlocks *and* invalid parameters. It may be easier to use Dapper for example. The way this class works, you need to *clear* the parameters first, add the new ones one by one, then call one of the `Execute` methods. If you forget to clean, or forget to dispose, you get errors and blocking, if not deadlocks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's been working fine so far, each time the DataAccess layer invoked, it will clear the parameter before adding a new one. A [condition] string is needed for Select function to filter the data based on the condition. With current String.Format, I can even drop the table using sql injection.

Comment: I honestly don't understand your issue then, though. Just feed the parameters into the `Parameters` property of `db` before calling `ExecuteReader` with the actual query text.

Comment: @Nyerguds yes, I can do that way, but it just not flexible enough as I just need to feed a condition string into the Select method. to add Parameters property, I need to create a new method just to filter that single data. Thanks for help anyway, I am just finding a way to convert condition string safely.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just a note, there may be "a single open connection for the the entire class's lifetime", but in the usage code it seems this SQLManager is created for every single query. It opens and closes a new connection _for each query_. Which, tbh, is probably worse... or quite a bit of overhead anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could build the SELECT query and assign it to SqlCommand object

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand

cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [DBO].[ACCOUNT] WHERE [Username] = @username AND [Password] = @pwd AND Active = 1")
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@username", txtName.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@pwd", txtId.Text))
```

Then pass parameter names and values using Parameters.Add method to [prevent SQL injection](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-tools/prevent-sql-injection-using-parameterized-query.aspx) as I also tried to explain at referred document.

Since your SQL query is more complex than the code above, you can build your SQL command dynamically by using a string query variables with parameter placeholders in it, then finally assign it to the SqlCommand object, too

Comment: He's using a manager class though, and its execute function clears and re-fills those from its own internal list.